# Moving iTunes tracks with all metadata

Tags: macos, itunes, music, metadata, music-management

I would like to move some iTunes tracks out of my iTunes library and off my machine while preserving all the associated metadata in the process. I'm hoping to accomplish this in a way that things like play count, date added etc will still be available if I decide to move these files back into my iTunes library at a later date. I am running OS X 10.9.4, and up to date iTunes. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Thanks for this! Closest thing I have got to an answer since I started this quest, and almost exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an answer for you, but you can see what is stored in file and what is stored outside of the file. That might help you narrow down your research a bit more:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3741061?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

The "Export Library" function (File -> Library -> Export Library) preserves playcounts, but the Date Added might get reset when you re-import the exported Library.